# Using curly bracket in H2 table name

Tags: h2

My application uses `MySQL` database and it has  table `utils.'{UserUtils}'`. I need to write a test that would use the same queries, but with the `H2` database for tests. But I can't create such a table in `H2`, I have error:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement 
  "create table utils.`{UserUtils}`[*]" [42000-196]
```

Is it possible to somehow tell `H2` to create such a table or are the names strictly limited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL, you need to enclose identifiers with special characters using back quotes (`). However, in H2 the correct way of using identifiers with special characters is to enclose them in double quotes ("). I just tried in H2 v1.4 without any trouble:

```
create table "{UserUtils}" (
  id int
);

insert into "{UserUtils}" (id) values (123);
insert into "{UserUtils}" (id) values (456);

select * from "{UserUtils}";
```

Returns:

```
ID           
-------------
123          
456
```

Maybe you are using an older/newer version of H2.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a problem. Yes, the table was created and the data was added. But in my program, all requests are focused on Working with `MySQL` database, and when I make such a request to the database H2 `select * from \`{UserUtils}\``, I have error: `Syntax error in SQL statement "select * from `{UserUtils}`[*]" [42000-196]`. So H2 can't work with such quotes?

Comment: MySQL and H2 are not 100% equal. Some SQL will work without modification, while other SQL will need to be modified. H2 has a "MySQL Compatibility Mode" (that can be enabled in SQL or in the JDBC url) but I'm not sure it will work. See http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility . Alternatively you could try other embedded/pure-JDBC databases such as HyperSQL or Apache Derby but I don't think they will support the double quotes, as you want; that's just a pure MySQL quirk. You'll need to try and see.

Comment: Well... why don't you go the other way around? MySQL can use [more standard] double quotes when you use the ANSI MODE (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes). If you use double quotes in MySQL, your life will be easier in H2, HyperSQL, or Apache Derby. Just an idea.

Comment: Unfortunately, this also does not work. In MySQL `SELECT *
FROM utils."{UserUtils}";` I have error: [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: In MySQL, did you set the mode first? `SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ANSI_QUOTES';`

Comment: Maybe there is a similar setting for H2? So that he takes the quotes `\`\``. This would be the best way for me

Comment: Sure it will, but I looked in the H2 docs and there's nothing about it: http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility